# Compiler error when using Java with GridDB

Tags: java, griddb

I'm trying to write a test Java program to access data in GridDB, similar to the example in the GridDB documentation here: https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/java/#simulate-iot-data-with-java.

Before putting any actual action into the program, I tried to compile it to make sure the compilation will work. At this stage, my code looks like this:

```
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.Collection;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GSException;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStore;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStoreFactory;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.Query;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.RowKey;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.RowSet;
import java.util.*;
public class GriddbTest
{
static class test1
{
@Rowkey String account;
String name;
String address;
}
public static void main (String[] args)
{
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("notificationAddress", "239.0.0.1");
props.setProperty("notificationPort", "31999");
props.setProperty("clusterName", "defaultCluster");
props.setProperty("user", "admin");
props.setProperty("password", "admin");
GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);
}
}
```

I included the @RowKey directive as per the sample program. However, when I compile it, I get the following error:

```
gsadm@Ubuntu:~$ javac GriddbTest.java
GriddbTest.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
@Rowkey String account;
 ^
  symbol:   class Rowkey
  location: class test1
1 error
```

So it's not recognizing the @Rowkey directive.

Is there something I need to have first set up in my environment in order for this directive to work?

Thanks a lot

I've tried going through the documentation to see if I have missed out any steps when installing and setting up environment variables, but can't find anything relevant

Comment: I’m not familiar with griddb, so here’s my general 2c thoughts.  All the griddb classes (including RowKey) will be in their jar file - have you downloaded that ?   Also using javac would mean you’re having to download that and its dependencies - have you tried maven (as described https://griddb.net/en/blog/using-maven-to-develop-griddb-applications/ ) ?

Comment: Check your CLASSPATH, if you have included required Jar files, from command-lie you could also use the -cp option.